# Using Shared Preferences for High Score saving

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Hell I am trying to make highscore for my project but my code is only saving last value not highest value
How can I store only highest value? here is my code .

This is saving process ->

```
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            TextView outputView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textscore);
            CharSequence textData = outputView.getText();

            if (textData != null) {
               editor.putString(TEXT_DATA_KEY, textData.toString());
               editor.commit();
            }
```

This is Reading process

```
  SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

  String textData = prefs.getString(TEXT_DATA_KEY, "No Preferences!");


            TextView outputView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textread);
```

Comment: You seem to be doing correct, what is the output? No Preferences! ?

Comment: it is saving last value not highest value

Comment: You need to check the previously saved value to see which is highest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the previously saved value to see which is highest else it you will just save the latest value, not the highest

E.g.

```
      if (textData != null) {
           int score = Integer.parseInt(textData.toString());

           if(score > prefs.getInt(TEXT_DATA_KEY, 0)) // Or get String, with parse Int.
           {
               //editor.putString(TEXT_DATA_KEY, textData.toString()); // Should be saved as int
               editor.putInt(TEXT_DATA_KEY, score);
               editor.commit();
           }
        }
```

Comment: The method getInt(String, int) is undefined for the type SharedPreferences.Editor

Comment: @Boldbayar You are right, use prefs as this doesnt have `.edit()` called on it. I jumped a step. p.s. you should be storing the score as an int using `putInt()` not a string.

Comment: i tried but there is no option to save it as Int can u show me ? :D

Comment: @Boldbayar See my edit. Use the `putInt` line, instead of the one above it. So you are `putInt` not `putString`

Comment: app is crashing but thanx for helping :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to store a new value only if the existing value in shared preferences is lesser than the new value.

You don't seem to be having this value check in your code

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
if (textData != null) {
               editor.putString(TEXT_DATA_KEY, textData.toString());
               editor.commit();
            }
```

with

```
if (textData != null) {
            if(Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString(TEXT_DATA_KEY, "0")) < Integer.parseInt(outputView.getText())) {
                editor.putString(TEXT_DATA_KEY, textData.toString());
                editor.commit();
            }
         }
```

Comment: You might be using different type of values for recording the score, you need to change the parsing accordingly.

Comment: The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (CharSequence)

Answer (score 0):

First of all why are you saving high scrore as string, use int or float (if you must).

The simplest way is to read high score before saving it and compare to the one you try to save.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to keep track of your in-game high score. That's easiest done using a number rather than using a text view's string:

```
int hiScore = 0;
```

In your startup, perhaps in onCreate(), you'll want to obtain the previous high score:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
try {
    hiScore = prefs.getInt(HI_SCORE, 0);

} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    hiScore = 0;
}
```

When a new score is obtained, you'll want to record it if it's higher than the previous high score:

```
if (newScore > hiScore) {
    hiScore = newScore;

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt(HI_SCORE, hiScore);
    editor.commit();
}
```